# Checking if an element is visible in Chrome using Selenium Remote WebDriver

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

Is there a cross browser solution to check if an element is visible using WebDriver? The solution for IE and firefox is to cast the object to a RenderedRemoteWebElement and then call the property Displayed.

I'm using the following methods to return if a element is visible:

```
/// <summary>
/// Check if the control is visible.
/// </summary>
public bool IsVisible()
{
    IWebElement control = mSelenium.FindElement(mFindBy);
    return ((RenderedRemoteWebElement)control).Displayed;
}
```

The problem is when I run this using Chrome, I get an exception when casting to type RenderedRemoteWebElement, this is not really the problem as I can catch this, but I need to a solution to check if an element is visible in chrome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should cast to `IRenderedWebElement` - Display is a property of that interface.